# Spring boot webflux only returning 401 and 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a `spring-boot project` that had `apache tomcat` but after reading about the benefits of reactive programming I decided to switch to `Reactor Netty` and `WebFlux`. 
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-reactor-netty) and managed to make it run unfortunately every request now returns a `401` and `403`. After googling I found that I needed to change my `Websecurity settings`. I needed to diable `csrf` like `http.csrf().disable()` and I did

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
 }
}
```

When I try to invoke an `endpoint` from my `TestController` it still returns `403` and `401`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/testmethod", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Mono<ServerResponse> test() {
    LOGGER.debug("test() method invoked");
    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(fromObject("Call received!")).log();
}
}
```

Below is the message I get in my log

```
    17:02:17.961 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [c9c29225] HTTP GET "/mytestapp/user/test"
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Processing */*
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Ignoring
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Did not match any media types
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Processing */*
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Ignoring
    17:02:17.992 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Did not match any media types
    17:02:17.993 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [c9c29225] Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

And if I call my user registration endpoint

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Mono<ServerResponse> registerUserAccount(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        final Mono<User> registeredUser = userService.registerNewUserAccount(passengerDto);
        return registeredUser.flatMap(user -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK).build())
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build()));
    }
```

But even this one returns

```
        17:07:02.849 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [c9c29225] HTTP POST "/mytesyapp/user/registration/passenger"
        17:07:02.852 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [c9c29225] Completed 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As I am not wrong, you have enabled the security and if it is spring-boot project then it look for authentication object. Try to access the service url in browser if it ask for username/password then you have to provide it to access the service.

The option here is to provide username/password from the place where you are accessing it(e.g. - Postman)

Comment: Interesting, where does the username and password come from? Doesn't spring boot allow to whitelist some urls and access without auth?

Comment: Yes, they can. You have to specify them. You have to provide the permitall access as you have given. If you configure spring-security it requires authentication to access the service.